# Can I run transformers in parallel if they’re being powered by two separate wall outlets?

Tags: transformer

I’ve seen people run two transformers in parallel from the same wall outlet. So one wall outlet powering two transformers. I was wonder If I could get two separate wall outlets and run 2 transformers in parallel that way or even more than two. Is it possible or would that not be function correctly if I used two separate wall outlets?

Comment: why would you want to do this? ... what problem are you trying to solve? ... your question should be about the problem, not about your solution to the problem

Comment: It is possible but the signals have to be in phase and close to each other in amplitude.  If you convert to DC each the same voltage and diode "or" them you can then convert the DC to AC. By far the best and safest solution is to get a bigger transformer.

Comment: Imagine the case with two secondaries tied in parallel, their primaries powered on different circuit branches. If a circuit breaker on one branch opens up due to an over-current, then the transformer tied to the still-active branch supplies power to its secondary, which now powers the other transformer's secondary and delivers an active mains voltage on the circuit that the breaker had tried to disconnect. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Here's a similar question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/681125/safety-of-dual-male-single-female-y-cords

Answer (score 5):

Whatever the necessity to do so, powering an electrical appliance using two outlets is a strict no-no for reasons of safety.

The risks / dangers could be as follows:

1. The risk of short circuit / electric shock / electrocution, through the live exposed pin, when one of the plugs is unplugged. Even a service technician, unaware of the non-standard practice, would be exposed to the risk.
2. The danger of a short circuit, should one of the outlets be wrongly wired (line and neutral swapped).
3. The danger of an overload / fire, should one of the circuit breakers trip or be switched off.

Answer (score 0):

First, by "transformer", do you mean an actual transformer - an iron core with primary and secondary windings on it, or do you mean a DC power supply that contains a transformer?

If you mean actual transformers, then yes, but only if you're careful.  The transformers should all be identical.  Make sure you connect the secondary windings the same way round.  If you have 2-phase or 3-phase mains, then they must all be on the same phase.  If the plugs in your country are not polarized, they must be the same way round.  Get it wrong, and huge currents can flow, destroying the transformers.

If you mean DC power supplies, check the manufacturer's data sheet.  Many are not designed to work in parallel.

Comment: Also if the mains plug and socket are not polarized, then, in addition to make sure same phase is used, the plug orientation must also be correct.

Comment: @Justme Good point - I will update the answer.

Comment: Your answers are usually very good but I think you should recommend that the OP does not try this. The OP has mentioned wall outlets and that means two plugs and that means live prongs on one when pulled out. It's too dangerous.