# Safety of dual male / single female Y cords

Tags: circuit-design, safety, circuit-protection, power-delivery, fail-safe

On Amazon there are Y cords with two male plugs and a single, higher current female socket.  These are advertised as providing a way to power equipment with higher current demands than a single outlet can support.

[image]

*(Picture from one such advert titled "ONETAK NEMA 2 Port TT-30P 120V 30 Amp 3 Prong Plug Male to 14-50R 120/240V 50Amp 4 Prong Female Receptacle Y Combiner STW 3 Feet Generator Welder Dryer Power Cord Adapter")*

If one of the legs of the Y connecting cord is unplugged from its corresponding power supply, whilst the other is still connected and powered, the disconnected male is now live.  This is why such a device is commonly called a "suicide cord".

Are there any devices on the market that can detect such situation automatically and mitigate the risk of a live male connector? Preferably a device that can be installed in-line on any leg of the Y connecting cord.

Comment: I don't really understand why someone would implement a system with such a "suicide cord". Can you give more details? Did you buy the Y cable, or splice it yourself? Can you give details about the power supplies? Their make and model?

Comment: Is this some sort of backup system, dual inputs for redundancy or something?

Comment: Use a manual mechanical, or automatic, [transfer switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_switch).  Suicide cords are called suicide cords for a reason; there is no need for more data points.

Comment: The Y cable is store bought similar to this: https://www.amazon.com/ONETAK-Receptacle-Combiner-Adapter-Connector/dp/B09JRRK48G

Comment: Power supplies are outputting 120V at 25A

Comment: "The Y cable is store bought similar to..."  Ya, those cables are just wrong.  There is no legitimate reason to use them.  IMHO, they should be illegal for sale in the US.  Do not do this.

Comment: I completely agree. I was just curious if there was anything on the market that would automatically mitigate that risk if someone where to disconnect a leg without turning the power supplys off.  Ive thought of possibly designing a mechanical switch that would be incorporated into the face of the plug that way when it's plugged in, the circuit is closed and when the leg us disconnected the circuit is open

Comment: Here's a similar question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/620080/can-i-run-transformers-in-parallel-if-they-re-being-powered-by-two-separate-wall/620089#620089

Comment: The linked Y-cord is intended to get 240 V from two 120 V outlets, NOT to get 30 A 120 V from two 15 A 120 V outlets as the "more power" implies.  The OP should have a 240 V outlet installed if his equipment requires 240 V.

Answer (score 2):

Those Y-cords are used to get 240 volts from two 120 volt outlets.  Some of the other answers and comments just say "to get more power than a single outlet would supply" without making this clear.

In the pleasure boat area, similar cords are used to allow a boat with a single 50 A 240 V power inlet to draw power from the more common 30 A 120 V shore power outlets.  At least one supplier of marine shore power cords makes a Y-cord with a "smart" box that prevents an un-connected male plug from being live.

Comment: This purpose makes more sense, but how would you make sure that the two 120V receptacles are not on the same leg of the 120/240V system?  Also, if you combine two 30A/120V outlets you would not increase the current.  You would just get a 30A/240V circuit. (And one that's not properly protected upstream since one side could trip independently.)

Comment: Yes - you have to make sure the two 120 V outlets are on opposite legs.  In a marina I'm familiar with, any two adjacent 120 V 30 A outlets are on opposite legs.  The common 240 V shore power inlet is rated at 50 A.  A boat using one of these Y-cords needs to keep the current drawn on each leg below 30 A

Answer (score 0):

I know cables like this are sometimes used to connect loads (such as welders) which exceed the rating of a single socket.  However, what you have is not code compliant, or legal for sale in most countries.

The only "semi-safe" version I have seen, includes a microswitch triggered by a plunger sticking out of the middle of the plug.  Unless the plug is fully home, the power pins are disconnected.

Having said that, I cannot recommend use of any cable of this nature, as there are too many unfortunate failure modes.

Rather than use a device like this, get an appropriate higher current outlet fitted.

If you were to *absolutely* insist on using such a device, you should ensure that both outlets are connected via plug in RCD/GFCIs.  These will not prevent a shock, but will limit the maximum length.

Comment: Do you have a link to said product?

Comment: I am not going to do anything to encourage you (or anyone else) down this path.

Comment: I am asking for a safe DIY home solution, you just suggested a solution that is safer to use then my original setup. Help me out here

Comment: Respectfully, abandon this idea, and use the time you save to directly wire in a higher power socket/feed.  That is the easiest and safest solution.  If you don't feel capable of that, get a professional electrician to do the work.  Live long and prosper!

Comment: I have edited my answer to both include the recommendation to fit a higher power outlet, but also to suggest use of RCDs/GFCIs if people insist on endangering themselves with the Y cable.